# Manatee.Json get human readable SchemaValidationResults output

Tags: c#, manatee.json

How can I print SchemaValidationResults in a human readable format (e.g. JSON)? [Documentation page](https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Json/usage/schema/validation.html) talks about different output formats (`JsonSchemaOptions.OutputFormat` property), but I cannot figure out how to get to text representation.

My code has the following pattern:

```
JsonSchema schema = _SchemaReader.Get(schemaPath);
JsonValue json = JsonValue.Parse(jsonDoc);
SchemaValidationResults validationResult = schema.Validate(json, new JsonSchemaOptions()
{
    OutputFormat = SchemaValidationOutputFormat.Detailed
});

validationResult.Should().BeValid(); // Custom FluentAssertions extension
```

Custom `FluentAssertions` extension code:

```
// Subject is SchemaValidationResults
Execute.Assertion.
    Given(() => Subject).
    ForCondition(s => s.IsValid).
    FailWith("Validation Errors: {0}", Subject.ErrorMessage);
```

But the resulting error message is: `"Items at indices [2,4] failed validation."` But I would like to see a more comprehensive output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is a recursive structure per draft 2019-09.  This means that further results are contained within the top-level structure.

In your case, you're looking for errors, so you need to look in the `validationResult.NestedResults` (previous edit had `.Errors`) property.  Here you will find the additional details you want.

---

Alternatively, you can change the output format to a flat list by setting `JsonSchemaOptions.OutputFormat = SchemaValidationOutputFormat.Basic;`.  This is also one of the output formats detailed in the specification.

Comment: I am looking at API documentation for `SchemaValidationResults` class and I don't see the `Errors` property. I can see `NestedResults` property, which is a list `SchemaValidationResults`, which I can traverse and read `ErrorMessage`. Is this what you propose?
https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Json/api/Manatee.Json.Schema.SchemaValidationResults.html

Comment: Yes, in the object model, it's `NestedResults`. When serialized, this is transformed to either `errors` or `annotations` depending on the valid state.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For my case I get the validation error list the following way.

```
public static List<string> GetValidationErrors(SchemaValidationResults validationResult)
{
    if (validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        return new List<string>(0);
    }

    var errorList = new List<string>(8);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(validationResult.ErrorMessage))
    {
        errorList.Add(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }

    foreach (SchemaValidationResults vrslt in validationResult.NestedResults)
    {
        errorList.AddRange(GetValidationErrors(vrslt));
    }
    return errorList;
}
```